# Bug in the Groovy 1.8.0 String class .tokenize(String) method?

Tags: groovy, gdk

Messing around with Groovy for a work project I ran into this oddity:

```
def string = "__RNDHPD(70.2300000..70.2310000)"
def params = []
string.find(/(?<=\().*?(?=\))/).tokenize("..").each { params << it.trim() }
// should yield [70.2300000,70.2310000] but instead results in [70, 2300000, 70, 2310000]
```

Using an alternative token works fine though. I don't think I am doing anything wrong, perhaps someone could shed some light on whether this my problem or something I should report to the Groovy devs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, the documentation is just very poor. The tokenize method is just a wrapper around [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), so the string you are passing to it is actually a list of delimiter characters. Try the [split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method instead.

```
def string = "__RNDHPD(70.2300000..70.2310000)"
def params = []
string.find(/(?<=\().*?(?=\))/).split(/\.\./).each { params << it.trim() }

assert params == ['70.2300000','70.2310000']
```